# Converter Char para string em C#

Tags: c#

Estou  tentando  converter um char  em string para usar  no  split(), porem  não está adiantando

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
path = path.ToString();
string[] caminho = path.Split("/");
```

Recebo o seguinte erro `Argumento 1:Não é possivel converter string para char`
tem  alguma forma de dazer isso ? 
esto utilizando  C# MVC asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está utilizando aspas duplas, que é o literal de `string`. Esse *overload* do método `Split` espera um `char`. Use aspas simples dessa maneira:

```
string[] caminho = path.Split('/');
```

Da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char):

> As constantes de tipo char podem ser escritas como literais de
>   caracteres, sequência de escape hexadecimal ou como representação
>   Unicode. Você também pode converter os códigos de caracteres
>   integrais. No exemplo a seguir, quatro variáveis char são
>   inicializadas com o mesmo caractere X:
>
> ```
> char[] chars = new char[4];
>
> chars[0] = 'X';        // Character literal
> chars[1] = '\x0058';   // Hexadecimal
> chars[2] = (char)88;   // Cast from integral type
> chars[3] = '\u0058';   // Unicode
>
> foreach (char c in chars)
> {
>     Console.Write(c + " ");
> }
> // Output: X X X X
> ```

Comment: o ToCharArray não serviria também? `string[] caminho = path.Split("/".ToCharArray());`

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas  e  vnbrs: [o **`Split`** tem _override_ pra `char[]` também](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx), mas não faria o mínimo de sentido usá-lo quando pode-se simplesmente trocar as aspas. A resposta dá o melhor caminho com toda certeza.